# loopback where filter on date's year

Tags: loopbackjs

I am not sure if database functions are supported thru REST API requests or if I am doing something wrong. I am using mysql db connector.

I have tried using simple where filter with both equality and gte operators.

```
{"where":{"YEAR(StartDate)":2018}}

or 

{"where":{"and":[{"YEAR(StartDate)":{"gte":2018}},{"year(StartDate)":{"lte":2020}}]}}
```

I don't get any error and the filter condition is silently ignored returning all records from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call functions from the query, you need to pass the values there. You may want to enable [the debugger](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html) to see what is going on and what queries are actually triggered. So, assuming that field name in the database is StartDate, you probably want to use something like this:

```
{"where":{ "StartDate": {"gte": new Date('2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')}} }
```

or, if and statement involved

```
{"where":{"and":[{"StartDate":{"gte":new Date('2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')}},{"StartDate":{"lte":new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')}}]}}
```

Comment: I think I'll accept your answer. I was just acting lazy to convert a single eq operator with a pair of gte/lte and some date manipulation. Thanks :)